Большой объем виртуальной машины vmware
Для работы использую виртуальную машину vmware на базе ОС Debian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm), машине выделено 200 ГБ памяти. В процессе работы заметил, что, при фактическом использовании 100 ГБ памяти:
$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           791M  1.4M  790M   1% /run
/dev/sda1       195G   94G   92G  51% /
tmpfs           3.9G   39M  3.9G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  8.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           791M   96K  791M   1% /run/user/1000

на диске хостовой машины виртуалка занимает уже 188 ГБ:

В виртуальной машине сделан 1 снимок состояния. В папке ВМ находятся 2 виртуальных диска, разбитых на 32 файла каждый (*-s001.vmdk - *-s032.vmdk), размером ~по 75 ГБ. С чем может быть связано такое превышение используемого дискового пространства виртуальной машиной над фактически занимаемым на хосте? Есть ли возможности "сжать" размер папки виртуальной машины?
